# symfony 1.4 - $this->getRoute()->getObject() call from helper

Tags: symfony-1.4

When I am using `$this->getRoute()->getObject()`, that works perfect. Is there a way to call `$this->getRoute()->getObject()` from helper.

When I call it from helper I got "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in..."

Comment: So, what's your problem??

Comment: Please edit your question according to [ask]! Thank you!

Comment: I'd rather think about pass the object to the helper...

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getController()->getAction(sfContext::getInstance()->getModuleName(), sfContext::getInstance()->getActionName())->getRoute()->getObject();
```

But it recommend you to pass the object as an argument instead of use `sfContext` in your helper.